# How to change size of td in xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Short question: how to adjust the size of a entire vertical row in html in xsl? Is it possible?

How do I change the size of td in a column? I wanted to show [image: this] but then it came out like this [image]. I couldn't make the A go to the second line. I think the problem is that the cell is too small so I wanted to enlarge it but I don't know how.

What I want: (the xml files are different so show different data but the requirements are the same)
[image]

What I have:
[image]

I know it is just a small difference but I hope to get it right ahhhh. Everything in the xsl file is same for all data cells but only the thunderstorm gives different display which I don't know how to solve.

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="part3.xsl"?>
<forecast queryTime="30/7/2021 14:10:20" queryLocation="Singapore">
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210617">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>6</month>
    <date>17</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Thu</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Considerable clouds</overall>
    <overallCode>cloudy</overallCode>
    <highest>29</highest>
    <lowest>19</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210612">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>6</month>
    <date>12</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Sat</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Cloudy with a thunderstorm</overall>
    <overallCode>thunderstorm</overallCode>
    <highest>28</highest>
    <lowest>23</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210709">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>7</month>
    <date>09</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Fri</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>A morning shower, then rain</overall>
    <overallCode>rain</overallCode>
    <highest>29</highest>
    <lowest>23</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210601">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>6</month>
    <date>01</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Tue</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Partly sunny</overall>
    <overallCode>partlySunny</overallCode>
    <highest>31</highest>
    <lowest>28</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210802">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>8</month>
    <date>02</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Mon</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Plenty of sunshine</overall>
    <overallCode>sunny</overallCode>
    <highest>35</highest>
    <lowest>24</lowest>
  </weather>
</forecast>
```

My xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/forecast">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    td {width: 100px;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="@queryLocation"/><xsl:text> [</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@queryTime"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text></h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#ffa500">
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Mon</th>
                        <th>Tue</th>
                        <th>Wed</th>
                        <th>Thu</th>
                        <th>Fri</th>
                        <th>Sat</th>
                        <th>Sun</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <xsl:for-each select="weather">
                        <xsl:sort select="month"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="date"/>
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="month = '6'">
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffa500" align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                                        <xsl:text> Jun</xsl:text>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="month = '7'">
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffa500" align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                                        <xsl:text> Jul</xsl:text>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffa500" align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                                        <xsl:text> Aug</xsl:text>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Mon'">
                                    <td align="center">
                                        
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Tue'">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Wed'">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>                                   
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Thu'">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>                                   
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Fri'">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>                                   
                                    <td align="center" class="rain">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall"/>
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Sat'">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:when test="dayOfWeek = 'Sun'">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
                                        <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                                        
                                        <img align="center">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                                                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            
                                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                                                <xsl:text>70px</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </img>
                                        
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="(overallCode = 'sunny')or(overallCode = 'partlySunny')">
                                                <font color="red">  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font> 
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="overallCode = 'cloudy'">
                                                <font color="green">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <font color="blue">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                                                </font>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </tr>       
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated !!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want a certain column width? Or just a line break after image before the text? The latter can be achieved with `<img .../><br/>`.

Comment: Honestly I just want a line break but I would love to know how to adjust a certain column width:) I tried the ```<img .../><br/``` but it didn't work also :(

Comment: Put each thing in a div. Your question is 100% not related to XSL. Write it in HTML so it works and then create the XSL to match.